# Logging and tracing changes of mapping a struct

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a struct and use it in mapping.

```
struct Cotton{
    uint256 balance;
    string form;
    address producer;
    string certificate;
}
mapping(address=>Cotton) public cotton;
```

I am able to access the last values of *cotton*. However, once there are many transactions I need to access the previous states of it as well.
I have tried emitting an event yet it does not accept a struct as an input argument.
Is there a way to retrieve all the changes on *cotton*?

Answer (score 1):

First, events don't support structs as for the current latest version of solidity (0.8.6), you need to pass specific value type variables (address, uint, etc) into the event.

```
...

// Event for cotton
event oracleCotton(uint256 balance, string form, address producer, string certificate);

...

// Emit event.
emit oracleCotton(cotton.balance, cotton.form, cotton.producer, cotton.certificate);

...
```

Also, there's no way to access previous states of data because whe moment you assign a new Cotton to an address, it will overwrite the previous one.

A solution for your issue would look something similar to this:

```
...

struct Cotton{
    uint256 balance;
    string form;
    address producer;
    string certificate;
}

struct CottonWrapper{
    uint256 counter;
    Cotton[] cottonHistory;     
}

mapping(address => CottonWrapper) public cotton;

...
```

And then...

```
// Logic to iterate over each cotton of an address.
for (uint i = cotton[address].counter; i > 0; i--) {
  Cotton memory c = cotton[address].cottonHistory[i];
  
  // Now here you can do whatever you want with that cotton.
  emit oracleCotton(c.balance, c.form, c.producer, c.certificate);
  
  ...

}
```